# Submit and do html form string in asp mvc controller side

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have html string like this in controller. I receive this from a web service (not important)

```
string str = "<form name='jy'action='https://' method='POST'><input type=submit value='Pay'></form>";
```

I should send this to a view and show it to the user, and user should click on submit and ...

But I want do this form and submit it automatically in controller side.

I mean no need to show this to user then user click on submit, it's useless.

How can I do this?

Comment: `<script>document.forms[0].submit();</script>`

Comment: i know that but how do this in controller side

Comment: "Controller" side? I don't get it. Do you mean "*Client*" side or "*Server*" side?

Comment: server side with c#

Comment: can i use Response.write()

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
ViewBag.addMe = String.Concat(str,"<script>document.forms[0].submit();</script>"); //(c)SomePerson
```

View:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.addMe)
```